# Convert Java Bean to XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, annotations

I have this problem. 
I would like to converter a bean java into xml file.
I would this :

```
public class Test(){

private String a;
private String b;

//getter and setter 

}

<ELEMENTS>
 <ELEMENT>
   <PROPERTY NAME="a">
     <PROPERTYVALUE>{VALUE_A}</>
   </PROPERTY>
   <PROPERTY NAME="B">
     <PROPERTYVALUE>{VALUE_B}</>
   </PROPERTY>
 </ELEMENT>
</ELEMENTS>
```

Thks

Comment: Should the output be exactly like this or similar like this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html

Comment: the output should be similar like that..thks